# Django CheckBoxSelectMultiple not working

Tags: django, forms, templates, widget

My website helps musicians connect and borrow/lend their instruments from/to one another.

I have a form on my webpage called `InstrumentSearchForm` which let's you search for an instrument by category, date and location.

```
class InstrumentSearchForm(forms.Form): 
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    location = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

This form is initialized in the `view` and passed to the template in the context (I caught out things that were unrelated clutter)

```
def main_page(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ....
    else:
        form_search = InstrumentSearchForm(prefix="search") # An unbound form
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form_search'] = form_search
    ...
    categories_to_show = Categories.objects.filter(users = request.user) #show users categories
    form_search.fields['categories'].queryset = categories_to_show
    return render(request, 'main_page.html', args)
```

The trouble is, that in the template page, when I say

```
{{ form_search }}
```

the form is missing the "**Categories**" widget. It only has the date and location boxes. In the source, it doesn't show any choices for Categories even though I know they exist.

I've been trying to figure out what the problem, with no results. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything necessarily wrong with the code you've posted, but I would put the logic into the form:

```
class InstrumentSearchForm(forms.Form): 
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.none(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(InstrumentSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'].queryset = Categories.objects.filter(users=user)
```

and instantiate it with:

```
form = InstrumentSearchForm(user=request.user)
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: Does it matter there is also another form in the page? I didn't mention it because they aren't really connected